# Using Chai, how can I assert the result of "git pull"

Tags: integration-testing, mocha, chai

I am using Mocha and Chai.js to test a function which executes `git pull` in a Terminal and I want to assert that it results in `Already up-to-date.`

How can I accomplish this? What is the best approach to take?

```js
    var assert = require('chai').assert;
    var cmd = require('node-cmd');
    
    describe('DEAN-Management', function () {
        describe('Update source', function () {
            it('check for updates', function () {
                cmd.run('git pull');
                assert.??;
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to capture the output from `cmd.run(git pull');`, e.g.

`out = cmd.run('git pull');`

then `assert out.match('Already up-to-date.')`

I don't know the exact syntax so adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with that command line library you're using but at a glance... The documentation states that cmd.get(command, callback(data)) accepts a command string and returns the results that were output to the callback function. To use it in a test I'd do something like this where assert.include is a partial match of the string "data".

```
it('your test', function(){
  cmd.get('git pull', function(data){
    assert.include(data, 'Already up-to-date.', 'Optional success message')
  }
});
```